# Defining Blogger Template Designer Variables

Tags: css, xhtml, blogger

I have been searching pretty extensively but I haven't been able to find any Google documentation on how to author a Blogger template that utilizes their template designer interface.

I'd like to create a variable that let's you easily set a background image for the main content div, or perhaps even upload multiple background images to an array for randomized background images, etc.

I found how to create color and font variables pretty easily but that's not really what I'm trying to do.

So, does anyone know either how to define new 'background' variables or know where to find documentation on how to write a Blogger template?

Thanks a lot for any help!

EDIT:
To clarify, I'm trying to define variables in my template that will be compatible with the built in Template Designer interface. For instance:

```
<Group description="Page Text" selector="body">
<Variable name="body.font" description="Font" type="font"
default="normal normal 12px Arial, Tahoma, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif" value="normal normal 12px 'Trebuchet MS', Trebuchet, Verdana, sans-serif"/>
<Variable name="body.text.color" description="Text Color" type="color" default="#222222" value="#666666"/>
</Group>
```

The above code will let me use Template Designer UI to change the CSS for the body font and the color of the body text. These are the only two variable types I can define from scratch that I can get to appear in the Designer interface ("font" and "color"). I am trying to define an image selector instead. The interface currently lets you choose one background image using this variable:

```
<Variable name="body.background" description="Body Background" type="background"
color="$(body.background.color)" default="$(color) none repeat scroll top left" value="$(color) url(http://example/example.png) repeat fixed top left"/>
```

But creating a new variable with this same convention won't cause anything new to show up in the Template Designer UI.

Thanks again!

Comment: have you try template designer feature?

Comment: Thanks, I think maybe I wasn't clear enough in my question. I'll edit it and make it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Blogger Template Designer is extremely basic and won't allow for you to have multiple upload opportunities. You will only be able to create one upload slot and this is reserved for the body background.
I found [this post](http://bloggerillustrated.blogspot.ch/2012/07/how-to-add-support-for-blogger-template-designer-in-custom-templates.html) extremely helpful with writing variables.
As for your question on documentation of how to write a blogger template. I have been writing responsive Blogger templates for quite a while now and have written multiple tutorials on it, but I focus more on the responsive part than the variables. But if you still would want to have a look, maybe you find something helpful. [link](http://bekreatief.blogspot.ch/2014/09/write-responsive-blogger-template-fast.html)

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid that was the answer. I don't get why google keeps these attributes locked away. The Template Designer could be so powerful if we had better access to it. :\ Also thank you very much for the link to your template tutorial. That's very, very useful!

Comment: yeah, I think Google should improove the designer greatly. In a few years it'll be completely unacceptable to have a responsive website, if Blogger won't be adapted, the service might be commiting suicide... I'm glad you find it useful :)

Comment: I think the fact that there hasn't been a post on the official  Blogger blog in 8 months tells us exactly what google plans to do with Blogger: nothing. :( I hope I turn out to be wrong on that one.

Comment: yeah, I hope that too. But blogger is one of the biggest plattform Google own, there are millions of users, I think it'd be really stupid to end it. But it's Google... sometimes they make really bad decisions...

Answer (score 0):

have you try this variable?

```
<Variable name="body.background" description="Body Background" type="background"
color="#f1f2f3"
default="#ea9c16 url(your-image-url) no-repeat fixed top center "
 value="#ea9c16 url(your-image-url) no-repeat fixed top center"/>
```

Comment: Hi! Unless I'm missing something that's the same variable I posted in my question and is already included in the Blogger template code. This is the variable that's hooked up to the wallpaper selector in the Template Designer UI already. What I'm trying to do is add a **new** variable in addition to the one that already exists. For example, the one you posted points to "body.background". I'd like to create one that changes the "content.background" for instance, and once I create this variable I want it to appear in the Designer UI so I can change images from there instead of in the CSS. Thanks!

Comment: you mean `content.background` for "main-wrapper" background?

Comment: Yeah, I know it's easy enough to just assign a background to the main-wrapper with CSS, but I wanted to be able to manage the uploads through the Template Designer interface. KreaTief has confirmed that that's not possible though. Thanks for your responses. :)

Comment: I think it's possible to do, the key is `name` variable (`name="variable.name"`), then just call the `variable.name` inside `b:skin` tag.

Comment: Is it a good practice to name the variable with a "." inside? Won't it cause a confusion with the "." for a class?